# Truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all() - possible issue with not()

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to add a new column in to a dataframe with a nested logic but I'm getting the error "Truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()". The solutions I've found online don't apply to my scenario.

```
#original case statement in sql
,case when pd.min_compare_at_price is not null then pd.min_compare_at_price else
        case when n.compare_price is null or n.compare_price = 0 then 
              case when min(n.sales_price) is null then 
                   case when n.sales_price is null and n.compare_price is null then max(n.original_price) 
                        when n.sales_price is not null and n.compare_price is null then max(n.original_price)
                        else n.compare_price end
                   else min(n.sales_price) end
              else n.compare_price end
        end as current_std_price
```

in python, the columns are all within the same dataframe 'product_data'

```
product_data['current_std_price'] = np.where(not(pd.isna(product_data['min_compare_at_price'])),product_data['min_compare_at_price'],
         np.where(pd.isna(product_data['compare_at_price']) | product_data['compare_at_price']==0,
                  np.where(pd.isna(product_data['min_price_prod']),
                           np.where(pd.isna(product_data['sales_price']) & pd.isna(product_data['compare_at_price']),product_data['original_price'],
                                    np.where(not(pd.isna(product_data['sales_price'])) & pd.isna(product_data['compare_at_price']),product_data['original_price'],
                                        product_data['compare_at_price']),
                                product_data['min_price_prod']))))
```

whilst troubleshooting this, I tried to cut it right down to just this but still had the same error:

```
product_data['current_std_price'] = np.where(not(pd.isna(product_data['min_compare_at_price'])),product_data['min_compare_at_price'],product_data['min_price_prod'])
```

I think the issue is with the `not` but I'm not sure on how to resolve it without flipping the logic which I want to avoid due to its complexity.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem is that logical operators in python will match against the whole object. What you want is to make a element-wise logical operation. You can use `numpy.logical_not()` for that or, in the special case of logical operation between array of booleans, you can use bitwise operations, which in the case is the `~` operator.

So, the following should work for you:

```py
product_data['current_std_price'] = np.where(np.logical_not(pd.isna(product_data['min_compare_at_price'])),product_data['min_compare_at_price'],product_data['min_price_prod'])
```

or

```py
product_data['current_std_price'] = np.where(~(pd.isna(product_data['min_compare_at_price'])),product_data['min_compare_at_price'],product_data['min_price_prod'])
```